# Getting a files extension from Filepicker-Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, filepicker

This is part of my activity class. By calling the below Intent i open a file-picker intent to select an image or video. This works so far.

```
public class Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText et;
    private static final int PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE = 1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // EditText to show filepath after intent
        et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et);

        // Start intent to pick a file
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.setType("image/*|video/*");
        startActivityForResult(intent,PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE);
    }
```

Here I retrieve the file's path:

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch(requestCode)
        {
            case PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE:
                if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){

                    // Get path of selected file and set it to editText
                    String filePath = data.getData().getPath();
                    et_upload.setText(filePath);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

The result looks like,

```
"/path/to/file/fileName".
```

but I want to include the files extension:

```
"/path/to/file/fileName.png"
```

Anything I missed?

Thank you in advance for any help. :)

Answer (score 1):

> This works so far.

`setType()` does not support the `|` operator.

> Anything I missed?

First, the path alone is meaningless. `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` will typically return a `content://` `Uri`, and the path is only meaningful to the `ContentProvider`. For example, this is not a path to a file on a filesystem.

Second, that `Uri` does not have to include a file extension.

If you want to know the MIME type of the content backed by that `Uri`, use a `ContentResolver` and [its `getType()` method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#getType%28android.net.Uri%29). If you want to convert that MIME type into a file extension, [use `MimeTypeMap`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/MimeTypeMap.html).